# Increase value / Script

Tags: javascript, timer, increment

I need some help with increases value / 1 per second.

I have

```
<script>
function incrementValue()
{
var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
value++;
document.getElementById('number').value = value;
return false;
}
</script>
```

Now I need a function that will increase the value of 'number' and start adding +1 every second until I click on another image.

The only thing I am capable of making is:

```
function incrementvale()
var incrementTime = 1;
var incrementBy = 1;
private var counter = 0;

function Start () {
InvokeRepeating("Increment", incrementTime, incrementTime);
}

function Increment () {
counter += incrementBy;
}
```

Which is horribly wrong!
Question!

When I click on image.

Function starts.

The function increases the value of 'number' by 1 every second.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to increase a value exactly after 1 second I would suggest you save the start time (Unix time stamp e.g. seconds since 1/1/1970). And if you want to know the value of your increasing variable just subtract from start value.

Because you mentioned PHP and showed us JS Code I keep it in Pseudo-Code

```
function getUnixTimeStampNow() {
    return Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
}

var start = getUnixTimeStampNow();

// at any time do

var current_value = getUnixTimeStampNow() - start;
```